# Could not resolve image_picker package import | Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, importerror, imagepicker, flutter-packages

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  settings_ui: ^0.6.0
  custom_switch: 0.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.17
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

[profile.dart package import section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSNLD.png)

I am not able to import **image_picker.dart** and so I can't use it's function.

I have run `flutter pub get` command.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your pubspec.yaml to this

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: 
  settings_ui: ^0.6.0
  custom_switch: 0.0.1
  firebase_core: 
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.17
  cloud_firestore: 
  image_picker: 
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

let me know if this work.

Comment: So, if we don't give any version then flutter automatically get best ?

Comment: you get error of firebase version. when you remove the version code then flutter automatically get the version. which is compatible with the other packages.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the add this  ^

```
 image_picker: ^0.7.4
```

Comment: I have added but still same problem